# python convert a negative integer into byte(singed=True), but convert back, it becomes positive

Tags: python, byte, signed

```
number = -127
array = number.to_bytes( 1 , byteorder='big' , signed=True )
```

only convert to a single byte

```
print( array[0] )

number_positive = 254
array = array + number_positive.to_bytes( 1 , byteorder='big' , signed=False )
```

then how should i print -127 and 254 separately out

if i just use `array[0] and array[1]` the answer would be two positive

any help is much appreciated
thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `int.from_bytes()` method to convert a byte back into an integer instead:

```
print(int.from_bytes(array, byteorder='big', signed=True))
```

Comment: thank you for replying what if array is constructed by two bytes, and i want to separate them and print it out

Comment: hi i added the question, sorry to bother you

Comment: Your updated question now includes both a signed integer and an unsigned integer in one array, so you won't be able to use the same logic to convert them back to integers, since you'll need `signed=False` for the number `254`.

Comment: so are you saying that no possible solutions?

Comment: hi the actually problem is for ip address of 4 bytes, i know there won't be any negative in ipv4,  i am just curious if i know there are four bytes and i want to separate them.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but the code would not be pretty because you would be hard-coding different logics for the first item and the second item in the array separately. For `array[0]`, you need `signed=True`, and for `array[1]`, you need `signed=False`.

Comment: thank you for replying  when i convert from int to byte, i can just use numbre.to_bytes( signed=True /False), but when i convert back to int, i can not use int.from_bytes( array[0] , byteorder='big' , signed=True ), there would be error, i can only use int.from_bytes( array , byteorder='big' , signed=False ) or print(array[0]), how to solve, purely out of curiouse, i know mostly likely, i won't meet such problem, btw, you answer is taken, thank you for your help

Comment: I see. You certainly need `signed=False` for all four bytes of an IPv4 IP-address. But then in that case, it's better to simply use `struct.unpack` to convert the array of 4 bytes to a tuple of 4 integers: `struct.unpack('BBBB', array)` (remember to `import struct` first.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using `abs`:

```
print(abs(number))
```

Or for both:

```
print(-number)
```